# Resizing views in a UITabBarController to not appear behind the tab bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application set up where the window contains a tab bar controller and one of the tabs loads a NIB called 'ShowCaseView.xib'; this file is owned by a custom `ShowcaseViewController` class.

In the `ShowcaseViewcontroller` class I have added a `UIScrollView` object, like so:

```
imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:imageScrollView];
```

The issue I am having is that this `UIScrollView` object extends ***beneath*** my tab bar controller.

So I have had to reduce its insets manually:

```
#define TAB_BAR_HEIGHT 48
.
.
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, TAB_BAR_HEIGHT, 0);    
[imageScrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:edgeInsets];
```

So,

- Is it common to have to manually deduct the tab bar height from a view (whether this be by reducing the size of subviews or the View NIB in inspector)?
- Is there a way that I can tell a NIB's view loaded from a tab bar to resize itself automatically to NOT sit behind the tab bar?

Comment: "Is there a way that I can tell a NIB's view loaded from a tab bar to 
resize itself automatically to NOT sit behind the tab bar? " . Not really get it, do you mean your scroll view not behind tab bar

Comment: Yes I want my scroll view not to appear behind the tab bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the NIB file is the "Size & Position" for the view set to "Frame"? I should be Layout.